# Unable to get gridview footer values in RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview

I'm creating a page to enter employee's leave details in a dynamic gridview. Entry of data will be done by the from the footer of the gridview. When I try to get the values from the footer, all the text values as well as other values are coming as null or "".

Here is the code of RowCommand:

```
protected void gvEmployeeDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("ADD"))
            {

                TextBox txtAddEmpID = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddEmpID");
                RadioButtonList rblFooter = (RadioButtonList)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("rblFooter");
                TextBox txtAddDoj = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddDoj");
                TextBox txtAddLeaves = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddLeaves");
                TextBox txtAddDesignation = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddDesignation");

                conn.Open();
                string cmdstr = "insert into tblLeaves(EmpId,IsActive,DOJ,Leaves,Designation) values(@EmpId,@IsActive,@DOJ,@Leaves,@Designation)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", txtAddEmpID.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", rblFooter.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOJ", txtAddDoj.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Leaves", txtAddLeaves.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", txtAddDesignation.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                BindData();
            }
        }
```

And below is the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvEmployeeDetails" runat="server" Width="100%"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True"
                    onrowcommand="gvEmployeeDetails_RowCommand"
                    onrowdeleting="gvEmployeeDetails_RowDeleting"
                    onrowupdating="gvEmployeeDetails_RowUpdating"
                    onrowcancelingedit="gvEmployeeDetails_RowCancelingEdit"
                    onrowediting="gvEmployeeDetails_RowEditing" style="text-align: center" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3">
                <Columns>           
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee ID">
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddEmpID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFooterEmpID" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddEmpID" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmpID" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EmpId") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>           
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEditEmpID" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EmpId") %>'></asp:Label>           
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblEdit" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblFooter" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFooterIsActive" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rblFooter" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblIsActive" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsActive") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Of Joining">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDoj" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DOJ") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>           
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDoj" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DOJ") %>'></asp:TextBox>           
                            <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="txtDoj_CalendarExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="txtDoj_CalendarExtender" TargetControlID="txtDoj" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddDoj" runat="server" MaxLength="10" OnTextChanged="txtAddDoj_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
                            <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="txtAddDoj_CalendarExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="txtAddDoj_CalendarExtender" TargetControlID="txtAddDoj" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFooterDOJ" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddDoj" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No. Of Leaves">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLeaves" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Leaves") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>           
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLeaves" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Leaves") %>'></asp:TextBox>           
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddLeaves" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFooterLeaves" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddLeaves" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDesignation" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Designation") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>           
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesignation" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Designation") %>'></asp:TextBox>           
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddDesignation" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFooterDesig" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddDesignation" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.png" Height="32px" Width="32px"/>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete.png" Height="32px" Width="32px"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon-update.png"/>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon-Cancel.png"/>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAdd" runat="server" CommandName="ADD" Text="Add" Width="100px"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                    
                </Columns>           
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Please correct me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I think the text values are being lost after your button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using sender in your find control code line. Try to replace below line.

```
TextBox txtAddEmpID = (TextBox)gvEmployeeDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddEmpID");
```

this.

```
protected void gridview_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Add") {
        TextBox txtAddEmpID = (TextBox)((GridView)sender).FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddEmpID");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yeah, I've tried this but still having the same issue. values still not coming.

Comment: If you are binding your gridview on page load then you must have to put check on page post back. So if page is not post back then bind grid only. That may be the case as well.

Comment: Oh yes...! that was the problem... Problem was with the postback not with the code. Thank you for your valuable suggestion... You just saved my day...:)